# What do the letters Dx - of diagnosis- stand for?

Tags: abbreviations

I always see the letters **Dx** as the abbreviation of *diagnosis*, but I never understand how does this letter relate to the word diagnosis which doesn't contain the letter **x**. Therefore my question is

> What do these two letters (Dx) stand for?

An example using these letters:
Dx: atrial fibrilation and right bundlebranch block. (in cardiology)

Comment: Example, please.

Comment: I added now, for your request.

Comment: It is likely a copy of the x in Rx (prescription)  As to the origin of that, here is some in depth speculation: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1641/what-does-the-pharmacists-symbol-rx-mean

Comment: relevant post on English Language and Usage: [Term for the second letter in Sx, Dx, Rx?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314546/term-for-the-second-letter-in-sx-dx-rx)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of abbreviations which use the first letter and an 'x'. The other ones I can think of are:

Rx - Latin *recipe* ("take" - the traditional first word of a recipe!)

Tx - *transmit/transmission*

Rx - *receive/reception*

I suspect that the practice goes back to scribal abbreviations, though I don't know for sure.

Comment: Here are some more: https://www.englishforums.com/English/OnGroundThoseAbbreviationsCreated/vvwx/post.htm

Comment: I think a lot of the replies on that forum are unsupported speculation, and probably wrong.

Comment: Probably! I didn't know about "Sx," "Fx" etc though.

Comment: No, I didn't, either. It is noticeable that all the examples we have are used in particular fields, effectively as professional jargon: I'm not sure that any of them will be understood by the general public, except possible Rx for a prescription.

Comment: Good information but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, it doesn't directly. It rather implies that the x stands for "the rest of the word".

Answer (score 1):

[***Dx***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/dx) is an abbreviation for a medical diagnosis or diagnostic (tool).

If you Google search on [**Dx diagnostics**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dx+diagnostics&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) you can find numerous references.

**dx** is also used in radio communications, but that meaning is different (included in the above definition).

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the manuscript practice of adding a crossbar to a letter to indicate that it's an abbreviation, like with Rx, the diagonal of the R was extended downward and crossed, so that it resembled a ligature of R and x. As typesetting was introduced, the lower-case x was a convenient way to represent such abbreviations.